# Where na lista com recyclerview

Tags: java, android

Preciso pegar a posição de um item da lista, onde o código seja o que passei. Em C# faço isso como linq, como fazer no java?

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(final LineHolder_Entidade holder, final int position) {
    Context holder_Context = holder.itemView.getContext();

    int oPosicao =  oEntidades.get(position).getCodigo();// onde o código == 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do seu adapter vc pode fazer um metodo assim

```
public int findBy(Int cod){
  foreach(Entidade e: oEntidades){
    if(e.getCodigo().equals(cod))
    return oEntidades.indexOf(e);
  }
  return -1;
}
```